# Not able to configure hotmail id with azure logic app

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a simple azure logic app as follows.

[image: Simple Azure Logic App]

Now I add a new action after the first one.

[image: New Action in Azure Logic Apps]

Select an email action.

[image: select email action]

Look for send email action

[image: send email action]

Now no mater what I do, I get this error

`Please check your account info and/or permissions and try again. Details: REST API is not yet supported for this mailbox. This error can occur for sandbox (test) accounts or for accounts that are on a dedicated (on-premise) mail server. clientRequestId: 9295041e-4d27-4d7f-8ac7-9f90f1cc65ff serviceRequestId: 17c7df3b-7f07-6d27-4f7b-68a4475e9b55 More diagnostic information: x-ms-client-request-id is '51B43F16-6D7C-4BE7-9AE2-7B4A6B73BA49'.`

[image]

I click **Change Connection** above and I see these increasing number of connection, and I find no way to delete them. See the last image at the bottom.

[image: Change Connection in Email action]

And when I click Save, I get this message.

`Save logic app failed. Failed to save logic app vivek-logic-app. Some of the connections are not authorized yet. If you just created a workflow from a template, please add the authorized connections to your workflow before saving.`

[image: Save the azure logic App]

And finally when I click Api Connections, I find no connections to delete.

[image: azure logic apps api connections]

So two questions.

1. How to authorize hotmail account te be used by Azure Logic App
2. How to delete the un-necessary connections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here it is after a good 3 hour PIA.

For the connections to manage(or delete), look at the resource group and not the Logic app.

[image: Resource Group for api connections]

And next for the send email action, choose Outlook.Com connection and not Office 365 Outlook. Found the [answer here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/275823/azure-logic-app-only-work-or-school-accounts-are-s.html). Mine is personal account and not for work or for school.

[image: outlook.com connection]

Once you setup this action successfully, you can take a look at [this](https://account.live.com/consent/Manage) page for managing the connection access.